# composer cannot find my installed package

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I have a package in a private github repository.

When I run `composer require my_vendor/my_package` the package gets added to composer.json and shows up in the vendor directory.

When I run `composer remove my_vendor/my_package` it gives me a warning:

> Package "my_vendor/my_package" listed for update is not installed.
>   Ignoring.

So when I run `composer prohibits my_vendor/my_package` it says

> Could not find package "my_vendor/my_package" in your project

If I run `composer show` (after requiring the package) it is not displayed in the list.

This package has a dependency (lexik/authenticationbundle) which is correctly installed, removed and show in list of installed packages (but not listed in the tree view since it is a dependency of a non existent package)...

I have no clue on what could explain this behavior.

Any suggestion?

**edit** (adding composer.json content)

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "api-platform/api-pack": "^1.1",
        "composer/composer": "^1.6",
        "symfony/console": "^4.1",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.0",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "^4.1",
        "symfony/lts": "^4@dev",
        "symfony/orm-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/web-server-bundle": "^4.1",
        "symfony/yaml": "^4.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "symfony/dotenv": "^4.1"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/my_repo/my_package.git"
        }
    ],
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd",
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-package-install": [
            "App\\Utility\\Bootstrap\\Setup::execute",
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "pre-package-uninstall": [
            "App\\Utility\\Bootstrap\\Demolish::execute",
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "id": "01C1K60FQVPP7FCAC3YB6639RZ",
            "allow-contrib": true
        }
    }
}
```

Furthermore, creating a new project and requiring the package correctly adds it to the list of installed packages, thus removing it works fine. Then I tried to delete lock file and running a composer update and eventually I tried to require/remove it but with no luck.

Comment: Show your `composer.json` content, where you require your package.

Comment: @dmnptr sure, added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that what was preventing composer to correctly configure required package was a `die()` in the `post-package-install` script.

Removing the statement solved the issue.